# Referencing explicit element id

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

My javascript function looks like this -

```
function updateSuccess(aEle) {
    //Here aEle doesn't have the correct id
    percIncrease.innerText = "Success";
}
```

in realizing it's bad to get the element this way, what would be a safer way of getting that element?

Some more info - 
Here is how I call it from C#..

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.ID = "ddlData1";

ddl.Attribute.Add("onchange", "updateSuccess('" + ddl.ClientID + "')";
```

Comment: how are you calling this function

Comment: i don see the parameter recordID used anywhere!

Comment: This is just a condensed version of my actual function..I name the element lblPerc1 in my custom control.

Comment: Just updated.. should I be calling it differently?

Comment: ehck my edit the answer for you ...

Comment: is that edited code work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

As per the edit in your question you just need to do this

```
ddl.Attribute.Add("onchange", "updateSuccess(this)";
```

**javascript**

```
function updateSuccess(element) {
              alert(element.id);
              document.getElementById(element.id).innerText = "Success";
              //or try below directly
              //element.innerText = "Success";
 }
```

---

I think you are using javascript with Asp.net for this you can do something like this

**Function declration**

```
function updateSuccess(recordID) {
     var percIncrease = document.getElementById(recordID);
     percIncrease.innerText = "Success";
 }
```

**call to function**

```
  updateSuccess('<%= serverelementID.ClientID %>');
```

**or directly like**

```
function updateSuccess() {
     var percIncrease = document.getElementById('<%= serverelementID.ClientID %>');
     percIncrease.innerText = "Success";
 }
```

Comment: I've tried this over and over and it never works. updateSuccess('<%= serverelementID.ClientID %>');  Visual studio doesn't like that syntax.

Comment: @duckmike - it the only way to get the clientid of element in .aspx file javascript... are you writing javascript in seprate file ???...if not and writing on .aspx page than this must work...

Comment: @duckmike - if you are using the javascirpt than you need to pass the value as in first code..